# Could not find any NvInferVersion.h, How do i change where it is looking for it?

Tags: tensorflow, build

When building tensorflow, i receive the following error.

```
Could not find any NvInferVersion.h matching version '' in any subdirectory:

    ''
    'include'
    'include/cuda'
    'include/*-linux-gnu'
    'extras/CUPTI/include'
    'include/cuda/CUPTI'
    'local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/include'
of:
    '/usr/include'
    '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
    '/usr/local/cuda-10.1'
```

However my NvInferVersion.h is located at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
How do i tell ./configure to check at that location? Where can i add this to the list of directories which it uses?

Answer (score 2):

./configure should prompt you for the following:

Please specify the comma-separated list of base paths to look for CUDA libraries and headers. [Leave empty to use the default]:

/usr/local/cuda-10.1, /lib, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot, /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib, **/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/**

You may also want to make sure that libnvinfer is properly installed as  described here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu